# How can I get a list of URLs of all images that appear on a webpage?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use VB.NET (2010) to get the absolute URLs of each image that appears on a specific webpage. So far, I've figured out how to get all of the URLs inside of an image tag, like so...

```
        For Each SeparateImage As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Images
        ListBox1.Items.Add(SeparateImage.GetAttribute("src"))
        Next
```

That works perfectly. But what I can't figure out is how to extract image URLs that appear within CSS styles. For example...

```
        background-image:url('image.jpg');
```

Does anyone know of a simple way to do this? I would need to extract the image URLs not only from inline CSS code, but from external stylesheets as well.

I reckon that one way to do it would be to grab the source code of the entire HTML page page and related CSS stylesheet, and then parse out all of the image URLs using a bunch of string splits and/or regex. But that could get pretty complicated to figure out the correct *absolute* URL of each image, because of all the different possibilities of "relative" URL paths I may come across. For example...

```
    background-image:url('image.jpg');
    background-image:url('/image.jpg');
    background-image:url('./image.jpg');
    background-image:url('../image.jpg');
    background-image:url('../otherdirectory/image.jpg');
```

So... it would be really nice if something like this existed...

```
        For Each CSS_Style As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Styles
        ListBox1.Items.Add(CSS_Style.GetAttribute("background-image"))
        Next
```

Does anyone know how I might be able to accomplish something like that? Or have any other ideas that don't involve mind numbing amounts of regex and logic? :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifically looking to avoid "mind numbing amounts of regex and logic", have you considered the [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) ?

The following brief code should show all image URLs contained within the HTML downloaded from the bbc.co.uk website.  It shouldn't be too hard to extend this code to parse the image links from any CSS files that are referenced from the HTML document.

```
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim mainUrl As String = "http://www.bbc.co.uk"
        Dim doc As HtmlDocument
        doc = New HtmlDocument()
        Dim sourceString As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(mainUrl)
        doc.LoadHtml(sourceString)
        For Each link As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]")
            Dim linkAddress = GetAbsoluteUrl(link.Attributes("src").Value, mainUrl)
            Console.WriteLine("Image: {0}", linkAddress)
        Next
    End Sub
    '
    Function GetAbsoluteUrl(partialUrl As String, baseUrl As String)
        Dim myUri = New Uri(partialUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        If (myUri.IsAbsoluteUri = False) Then
            myUri = New Uri(New Uri(baseUrl), partialUrl)
        End If
        GetAbsoluteUrl = myUri
    End Function

End Module
```